# Copy the updated shell script to EC2 without recreating it every time

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to copy the shell script to the running ec2 every time the shell scripts get updated.

The main requirement is I do not want the running EC2 to be stopped recreated or rebuilt, but Terraform should just copy the updated shell script from local to inside the running EC2 instance.

Below is my code using null_resource and triggers based on the script file's sha256 changes. But it destroys the EC2 and Elastic IP and recreates fresh ones every time when I try to run `terraform apply`.

Kindly help.

```
resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2" {
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 20
  }
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.server_instance.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.server_sg.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet_a.id
  associate_public_ip_address = false
}

resource "aws_eip" "server_eip" {
  domain = "vpc"
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip-association" {
  instance_id   = aws_instance.my-ec2.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.server_eip_eip.id
}

resource "null_resource" "shell_script" {
  triggers = {
    script_sha = sha256(file("${path.module}/script.sh"))
  }
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./script.sh"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/script.sh"
  }
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = tls_private_key.server_instance.private_key_openssh
    host        = aws_eip.server_eip.public_ip
  }
}
```

The terraform plan output shows the following, it says it will do the replacement of Elastic IP -> EC2 along with shell script update. I don't get why.

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource
actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

      # aws_eip_association.eip-association must be replaced
    -/+ resource "aws_eip_association" "eip-association" {
          ~ id                   = "eipassoc-0c2d1f2b1622c8944" -> (known after apply)
          ~ instance_id          = "i-0a40c91f920bd27e0" # forces replacement -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
          ~ network_interface_id = "eni-07fc89a7a961ca3ff" -> (known after apply)
          ~ private_ip_address   = "172.16.0.231" -> (known after apply)
          ~ public_ip            = "54.#.#.#" -> (known after apply)
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
        }
    
      # aws_instance.my-ec2 must be replaced
    -/+ resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2" {
          ~ arn                                  = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:575725418355:instance/i-0a40c91f920bd27e0" -> (known after apply)
          ~ associate_public_ip_address          = true -> false # forces replacement
          ~ availability_zone                    = "eu-west-1a" -> (known after apply)
          ~ cpu_core_count                       = 1 -> (known after apply)
          ~ cpu_threads_per_core                 = 2 -> (known after apply)
          ~ disable_api_stop                     = false -> (known after apply)
          ~ disable_api_termination              = false -> (known after apply)
          ~ ebs_optimized                        = false -> (known after apply)
          - hibernation                          = false -> null
          + host_id                              = (known after apply)
          + host_resource_group_arn              = (known after apply)
          ~ id                                   = "i-0a40c91f920bd27e0" -> (known after apply)
          ~ instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "stop" -> (known after apply)
          + instance_lifecycle                   = (known after apply)
          ~ instance_state                       = "running" -> (known after apply)
          ~ ipv6_address_count                   = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ ipv6_addresses                       = [] -> (known after apply)
          ~ monitoring                           = false -> (known after apply)
          + outpost_arn                          = (known after apply)
          + password_data                        = (known after apply)
          + placement_group                      = (known after apply)
          ~ placement_partition_number           = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ primary_network_interface_id         = "eni-07fc89a7a961ca3ff" -> (known after apply)
          ~ private_dns                          = "ip-172-16-0-231.eu-west-1.compute.internal" -> (known after apply)
          ~ private_ip                           = "172.16.0.231" -> (known after apply)
          + public_dns                           = (known after apply)
          ~ public_ip                            = "54.#.#.#" -> (known after apply)
          ~ secondary_private_ips                = [] -> (known after apply)
          ~ security_groups                      = [] -> (known after apply)
          + spot_instance_request_id             = (known after apply)
        }
    
      # null_resource.shell_script must be replaced
    -/+ resource "null_resource" "shell_script" {
          ~ id       = "7785759108528064923" -> (known after apply)
          ~ triggers = { # forces replacement
              ~ "script_sha" = "d3d741441a86d7928d58ea9596bd2b57d8556953e81064d937136301759f8fe9" -> "1fb47cc144844c24a25b92ca1b03147b50daa0ab49f016eb6637de9845404639"
            }
        }
    
    Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 3 to destroy.
    
    Changes to Outputs:
      ~ Instance_id                   = "i-0a40c91f920bd27e0" -> (known after apply)
```

Comment: Also consider SSM automation.

Comment: "recreates"  Do you have a plan snippet that demonstrates this behavior and explains why it is occurring?

Comment: Maybe the private keys are somehow changed across deployments?

Comment: @MattSchuchard all it says eip must be replaced which forces ec2. I don't get the point.

Comment: @MarkoE but there is no we are making with the ssh key right, just some changes in the shell script only, so no state change happens for the ssh key.

Comment: The output shows this is the reason for instance to be recreated: `associate_public_ip_address`. It changed from `true` to `false`

Comment: @MarkoE comment is root cause. Adding the plan output has revealed that parameter is causing the recreation, and that your `null_resource` is completely fine for updating the file on the instance.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I still don't get it :( where do you see in the plan output that private ssh key change is the root cause? But I am not doing anything with the ssh key.

Comment: @MarkoE if you check the code "associate_public_ip_address" is already false, I did not touch with it. All I did was add a new function inside the bash script and ran terraform plan and I saw this output and it does not make sense to me. If you want to verify, please run this code and see :)

Comment: This line is a clue: `~ associate_public_ip_address          = true -> false # forces replacement`. Can you explain why do you need that line? How is your subnet configured (esp. `map_public_ip_on_launch` parameter)?

Comment: @STerliakov The main reason I set "associate_public_ip_address = false" inside because I did not want to enable "auto assign IPv4 address" from its subnet when provisioning the EC2, instead I wanted to only attach the EIP I am creating. But this is the actual problem here.

Comment: @MarkoE you were right man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`associate_public_ip_address` attribute is forcing your ec2 recreation, and it is changing because your subnet might have `map_public_ip_on_launch` to `true` and hence it is setting this attribute to all ec2 instances launched in this subnet.

Once you set `associate_public_ip_address` to `true` you won't experience the same behavior.

```
resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro" # was t3.medium

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 20
  }
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.server_instance.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.server_sg.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet_a.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true ## <-- This was the probelem Earlier false --> ##
}
```

Please check your subnet on the AWS Console in which you are deploying this EC2 Instance, it must have the `Auto-assign public IPv4 address` to `Yes`.

You can also check it via terraform by adding output and doing `terraform plan` , considering the subnet is already created.

```
output "subnet_option_map_public_ip_on_launch" {
  value = aws_subnet.public_subnet_a.map_public_ip_on_launch
}
```

You will get below response

```bash
+ subnet_option_map_public_ip_on_launch = true
```